# Initializing Firebase app gives undefined for projectName

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase project with a web app, and I'm trying to initialize the app in JavaScript:

```
function load(callback){
    var script1 = document.createElement('script');
    var script2 = document.createElement('script');
    script1.src= "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase-app.js";
    script2.src= "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase-database.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script1);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script2);
    script2.onload=function(){callback()};
}

function process()
{
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "[my API key]",
        authDomain: "[my auth domain]",
        databaseURL: "[my database URL]",
        projectId: "[my project ID]",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "[my messaging sender ID]",
        appId: "[my app ID]"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    console.log(firebase.app().projectName)
}

load(process)
```

This code runs, but the console outputs undefined for projectName. When I output firebase.app().name, it gives [DEFAULT]. This means that despite not acknowledging it, the Firebase app doesn't load properly. As a result, I get errors when trying to use the realtime database. What might be causing the app not to load?

**EDIT**

When, after console.log, I add the line

```
database = firebase.database()
```

I get the following console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FIREBASE_DATABASE_EMULATOR_HOST' of undefined
    at Pi.databaseFromApp (RepoManager.ts:97)
    at Object.Mi.INTERNAL.registerService.Reference [as database] (index.ts:42)
    at I._getService (firebaseApp.ts:161)
    at I.a.<computed> [as database] (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:239)
    at Object.i [as database] (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:219)
    at process (07606b2d-18cf-46b2-afb2-20cff07eb8d6:32)
    at HTMLScriptElement.script2.onload (07606b2d-18cf-46b2-afb2-20cff07eb8d6:14)
```

After that, I cannot read any values from the database whenever I try.

Comment: Your code is initializing Firebase just fine.  `[DEFAULT]` is what you expect to see for the app name.  There is no property of the App object called "projectName".  Please edit the question to show the specific errors and code that causes them.

Comment: Thank you, I added the specific error message I get when referencing the database.

Comment: I would file a bug report on GitHub about this.  Make sure you have a fully complete, reproducible code sample that anyone can run to duplicate this.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk

Answer (score 0):

From firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup):

Initialize Firebase with a default Firebase project

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Initialize Firebase with a second Firebase project

```
var otherProject = firebase.initializeApp(otherProjectFirebaseConfig, "other");

console.log(firebase.app().name);  // "[DEFAULT]"
console.log(otherProject.name);    // "otherProject"
```